# Is there a way to use presentViewController animation in transitionWithView?

Tags: ios

I am using `transitionWithView` to have an animation when switching root view controller, but the animation options pvorided in `UIViewAnimationOptions` parameter does not have the animation like the `presentViewController` animation.

Is there a simple way to do it? Or how do I write an animation exactly the same as `presentViewController` animation?

Here's the animation I am using:

```
if (animated) {
    [UIView transitionWithView:self.window duration:0.3
                       options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft
                    animations:^{
                        weakSelf.window.rootViewController = weakSelf.loginNavigationController;

                    }
                    completion:^(BOOL finished) {

                    }];
}
```

Comment: `presentViewController` has four built-in animations. Which one do you want?

Comment: the new destination view controller will move from bottom to the top animation. could you provide the 4 options? I can check it. I just cannot find it in the UIViewAnimationOptions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I do something similar in one of my apps.

I don't try to do this while changing root view controllers. Instead, I have one root view controller that is always there. I make this a *custom parent view controller*. Its child view controller *looks* like the root view controller because it occupies the whole window.

Now, when I replace the child view controller, I call `transitionFromViewController:toViewController:duration:options:animations:completion:`. This has the advantage that I can write my own animation.

As you can see, it is then trivial to have the animation be a slide up from the bottom; you are in complete control of how the view animates into place:

[image]

Comment: Hey matt, but I don't see which animtion option you are using?

Comment: and due to some limitation/history reason I have to switch the root view controller for login feature and normal home view controller. Rewrite is not that easy. So I found the `transitionWithView` trick on SO, it works, but just lacks the animation like presentViewController

Comment: I see, you write your own animation code. Do you mind share it? I had my own, but a little buggy, not sure if related to the root view controller stuff. There is a black screen while moving up and down in my code.

Comment: I've shown you the way out of the problem. (You were using `transitionWithView` incorrectly anyway.) Using `transitionFromViewController:toViewController:...` lets you do exactly what you are asking to do - replace one view controller by another, not as a presented view controller but as a complete replacement, with control over the animation of their views as you do so. The screen shot shows that the result is exactly what you are asking for. At the end, the first view controller (the one with the yellow background) is gone forever.

Comment: Hey matt I think transitionFromViewController does not work for me, because I have to replace the root view controller, but transitionFromViewController's documentation says `This method adds the view in the toViewController view controller to the superview of the view in the fromViewController view controller.` , which just replaced the view, not controller

Comment: Is there a way to correctly animate the views when I want to replace the root view controller?

Comment: No because there is no supervening view controller in whose view the change can take place. That is why my answer says what it says.

Comment: hey matt, I tried your suggestion and self answer my version of code, could you please take a look, is it ok to do it like this way? I am very new to the container view controller, I tried my best not to cause bugs.

Answer (score 0):

I follow matt's suggestion, made below code change:

first in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    ...
    // the container view controller
    self.window.rootViewController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
    if (!SharedInstance.accessToken) {
        self.loginNavigationController = [self getNewLoginNaivigationController];
        [self.window.rootViewController addChildViewController:self.loginNavigationController];
        [self.window.rootViewController.view addSubview:self.loginNavigationController.view];
        [self.loginNavigationController didMoveToParentViewController:self.window.rootViewController];
    } else {
        self.rootHomeViewController = [self getNewRootHomeController];
        self.AppNavigationController = [self getNewAppNavigationControllerFromRootHomeViewController:self.rootHomeViewController];
        [self.window.rootViewController addChildViewController:self.rootHomeViewController];
        self.AppNavigationController.delegate = nil;
        [self.window.rootViewController.view addSubview:self.rootHomeViewController.view];
        [self.rootHomeViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self.window.rootViewController];
    }
}
```

Then when I want to change it:

```
-(void)displayHomeViewControllerWithAnimation:(BOOL)animated {
    if (!self.rootHomeViewController) {
        self.rootHomeViewController = [self getNewRootHomeController];
        self.AppNavigationController = [self getNewAppNavigationControllerFromRootHomeViewController:self.rootHomeViewController];
        self.AppNavigationController.delegate = nil;
        [self.window.rootViewController addChildViewController:self.rootHomeViewController];
    }

    // animation
    __weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;

    [self.loginNavigationController willMoveToParentViewController:nil];
    if (animated) {
        [self.window.rootViewController transitionFromViewController:self.loginNavigationController
                                                 toViewController:self.rootHomeViewController duration:0.3
                                                          options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear animations:^{
                                                              // do animation here                
                                                          } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                                                              [weakSelf.rootHomeViewController didMoveToParentViewController:weakSelf.window.rootViewController];
                                                              [weakSelf.loginNavigationController removeFromParentViewController];
                                                              weakSelf.loginNavigationController = nil;
                                                          }];
    } else {
        [weakSelf.rootHomeViewController didMoveToParentViewController:weakSelf.window.rootViewController];
        [weakSelf.loginNavigationController removeFromParentViewController];
        weakSelf.loginNavigationController = nil;
    }
}
```